# Is there a logical interpretation for equalizer and co-equalizer?

Tags: logic, category-theory, propositional-calculus, sheaf-theory, universal-property

I know the logical equivalent to several universal constructions. For example product $\times$ is $\land$ and co-product $+$ is $\lor$. The associated arrows are projection and inclusion. The [equalizer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equalizer_%28mathematics%29) arrow is an arguably even simpler construction, is there a logical interpretation?

For the [co-product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coproduct), say, I can say "If I know $C$ follows from $A$ and also $C$ follows from $B$, why not store this information in the statement that $C$ follows from $A\lor B$." and I picture the universal property diagram.

Now the equalizer, with two parallel arrows, is a little more tricky. Because if the logic only care for proofs, $C$ from $A$ say, then you've won when there is just one arrow. I figure answer will someone has that there is a sub-assumption $A'$ that's sufficient for the proof of $C$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Equalizers and coequalizers play an essential role in categorical quantifier logic.  (See Makkai and Reyes, *First-order categorical logic*.)

Equalizers are used to interpret the equality relation (in a first-order language).  In particular, let $\{x:t\}$ denote a term in context, which means that $t$ is a term of type $A_1,...,A_n;B$ and $x$ denotes a sequence of variables, including the variables free in $t$.  In an interpretation $M$, $M(\{x:t\})$ will be a function from $M(A_1)\times \cdots \times M(A_n)$ to $M(B)$.  Then $M(\{x:t=t'\})$ is defined to be the equalizer of the functions $M(\{x:t\})$ and $M(\{x:t'\})$.

Similarly, coequalizers are used to interpret quotient types.  In particular, if $E$ is a definable equivalence relation on a sort $A$, and if $p,q:E\to A$ are the  projections, then the equalizer $e:A\to A/E$ of $p$ and $q$ gives the projection onto the quotient type.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have a little problem to parse the sentence "let {x:t} denote a term in context, which means that t is a term of type A1,...,An;B and x denotes a sequence of variables, including the variables free in t." (Knuth says don't start a sentence with a mathematical symbol ;). So is '{x:t}' or 't' the "term in context"? Do you mean 't' is a term of type 'A1', 'A1,...,An' or 'A1,...,An;B'? I guess the second. As far as I can tell from the sentence below, you consider the category of contexts and arrows are terms. Then M is a functor and the codomain seemingly has products.

Comment: Let L be a language of many-sorted first-order logic.  That is, L consists of a collection of sorts A1,A2,..., a collection of function symbols, and a collection of relation symbols.  The function symbols are required to be typed.  For example, a function symbol f(x,y) might be of type "A,B;C" which means that "f" can be applied to terms of type A and B, and the result is a term of type C.  We can then define terms recursively, in the standard way.  And then we can define terms in context to be pairs {x:t} where x is a finite sequence of variables, containing all those free in t.

Comment: For a first-order theory T, the "syntactic category" C(T) has formulas as objects, and (equivalence classes of) provably functional relations as arrows.  Terms are always provably functional relations, and hence give rise to arrows.  Then an interpretation of the theory T amounts to a functor from C(T) into an appropriate category E.  In order to interpret conjunction, E must have pullbacks.  In order to interpret equality, E must have equalizers.  Etc..  Besides the Makkai and Reyes' book mentioned above, this construction is also explained in Part D of Johnstone's _Sketches of an Elephant_.

Comment: I think I read about it in Barts "Categorical logic and type theory". Do the formulas essentially represent predicates of properties of the objects of the models? I.e. I.e. an object $\phi$ in $\mathrm{C}(T)$ might be a predicate and a set $M(\phi):=\{x\,|\,\phi(x)\}$ might be the model. Is my interpretation right?

Comment: Yes, this is basically how it goes.  An object in $C(T)$ is a formula in context, written $\{\vec{x}:\phi \}$ where $\vec{x}$ contains all free variables in the formula $\phi$.  A Tarski-style interpretation of $T$ is a functor from $C(T)$ to the category of sets, and so maps the object $\{\vec{x}:\phi\}$ to a set $M(\{\vec{x}:\phi\})$.

Comment: You keep saying "contains all free variables", do you emphasize that it might consider more?

Comment: Yes, it makes things easier to allow this case.  For example, if $\phi$ and $\psi$ contain different free variables, we still want to be able to define $M(\{\vec{x}:\phi\wedge \psi\})$ in terms of $M(\{\vec{x}:\phi\})$ and $M(\{\vec{x}:\psi\})$.  But $\vec{x}$ is a sequence that contains the variables free in _both_ $\phi$ and $\psi$.

Comment: Okay, then one last question: I've seen the category of context only in the Bart book and then mentioned in connection with computer science people? Who uses this construct? In particular, I'm a physicist and not convinced it's work looking at it further.

Answer (score 8):

Your 'logical category' is a preorder, ordered by entailment: objects are propositions, and there is an arrow $A \to B$ if and only if $A$ implies $B$. So there is at most one morphism between any two objects.

Equalizers and coequalizers in preorder categories are kind of boring, since any diagram of the form
$$A \overset{f}{\underset{g}{\rightrightarrows}} B$$
must have $f=g$. (Both $f$ and $g$ are just the statement "$A$ implies $B$"!)

So in any preorder category, and in particular your proposition-and-entailment category, we have
$$\mathsf{eq}(A \rightrightarrows B) = A \qquad \mathsf{coeq}(A \rightrightarrows B) = B$$
as you can very easily verify.

This even extends to the case where a morphism $A \to B$ is a proof of $B$ from $A$, so that there may be more than one morphism from $A$ to $B$. The key is that any morphism $C \to A$ automatically commutes with the equalizer diagram: just stick the proofs one after the other.

Comment: Okay. The question arose in thinking about how the subobject classifier of a non-classical topos works (presheaf-category in particular). Since people say this gives a logic and, by the Yoneda lemma, its arrow structure will generally by quite full, don't I get more than just single arrows between two objects?

Comment: @Nifty: The structure of a topos looks more like a set theory / type theory / higher order logic, and less like a boolean algebra.

Comment: @Hurkyl: And you say there is no clear logical interpretation, say in terms of higher order logic?

Comment: I think the interpretation is as the solution set / type defined by / unary relation defined by an equation $f(x) = g(x)$.

Comment: I don't understand the last paragraph of the answer: if morphisms are proofs and $f\ne g\,:A\to B$ then we also have $h\circ f\ne h\circ g$ for any other proof $h:B\to C$.

Comment: In Clive's answer, the morphisms aren't proofs, the morphisms are assertions "there is a proof".